# covariant return or generic

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, covariance

I want to have a method in an interface that returns a class whose type is not defined in the package. The implementing class will then return a specific type. I can see at least 3 methods how I can do this, shown below as `fn1`, `fn2` and `fn3`. In all cases there is some form of unchecked cast. Is any of these methods preferred? or is there something better? (assume that the interface `I1` and the method `dostuff` are in some other jar package and do not have access to the `Test` or the `Integer` class)

```
public class Myclass {

    public interface I1
    {
        Object fn1();
        <T> T fn2();
        <T> T fn3();
    }

    public class Test implements I1
    {

        @Override
        public Integer fn1() {
            return new Integer(1);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T fn2() {
            return (T) new Integer(2); //requires cast to T
        }

        @Override
        public Integer fn3() { //automatic unchecked conversion to T in return value
            return new Integer(3);
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myclass c = new Myclass();      
        I1 t = c.new Test();
        Integer i = (Integer) t.fn1(); //cast required here since I1.fn1() returns Object
        Integer j = t.fn2();
        Integer k = t.fn3();
        dostuff(t);

    }

    static void dostuff(I1 p)
    {
        Object i = p.fn1();
        Object j = p.fn2();
        Object k = p.fn3();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use generics with the Interface? Like

```
public interface I1<T> {

    T fn1();
    // etc

}
```

Then there's no casting required when you refer to T.

That's what I prefer, at least. You can then also of course specify what you want T to be using

```
<T extends myInterface>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
public interface I1<T> {
    T fn1();
}

public class Test implements I1<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer fn1() {
        return new Integer(1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass c = new Myclass();
    I1<Integer> t = c.new Test();
    Integer i = t.fn1();  <-- no cast
}
```